# Set up a password policy that has a maximum failed login attempts and a reset after a certain period of time

Tags: snow-leopard, security, password

I tried using pwpolicy to set this up.  I was able to set up maxFailedLoginAttempts, but setting minutesUntilFailedLoginReset doesn't seem to do anything.  When I query pwpolicy using:

```
 pwpolicy -n /Local/Default -getglobalpolicy
```

I keep seeing that minutesUntilFailedLoginReset=0 even though I just set it to 60.  I even tried changing this for one user, and it claims it was changed but when I query the user's policy or the effective policy nothing has changed.

Comment: Post the commands you’re using to set the pwpolicy please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming that you’re aware that pwpolicy doesn’t affect Admin accounts (tho it may show you otherwise, leading to believe that it does).

I also asume that you’re running the commands as sudo or at least have tried.

Other than that, I haven’t tried that value myself. As a side (and curious) note the minutesUntilFailedLoginReset is **not** in the manpage for pwpolicy.

```
man pwpolicy
```

Comment: I used a standard account (not an admin) for my tests.  I ran the commands using sudo.  It is weird that minutesUntilFailedLoginReset isn't in man.  Thanks.

Comment: I couldn’t find other reference to it in the OS X documentation, I think you might be out of luck. Leave the question open to see if somebody comes in the future with a better idea. Good luck!